# Запятая после «поэтому» — без неё никак?

Tags: запятые, союзы

Вопрос возник из Галининого примера:

> Поэтому, как только ко мне обращались за «телефончиком», я показывала на Диму и капризно выговаривала: вот у него спросите.

Придаточное *"как только... «телефончиком»"* можно опустить, поэтому оно выделяется запятыми. То есть постановку запятой точно можно оправдать.

*Но нельзя ли также обойтись и без неё, отнеся поэтому **к придаточному**?*

Интересуют и другие примеры с *поэтому,* например *поэтому(,) когда.* Понятно, что если главное продолжается словом *то,* то запятую не ставят. А если нету *то,* всегда ли она нужна?

Answer (score 3):

Отнести это слово к придаточному можно только по смыслу, а для этого его нужно изменить, например:

> (Если не спрашивают, я никогда не раскрываю ничего о себе, тем более -
>   без разрешения мужа.)
>   **Поэтому только когда** ко мне обращались за «телефончиком», я показывала
>   на Диму и капризно выговаривала: вот у него спросите.

Для сравнения - похожий пример из книжки про Карлу Бруни (Бесма Лаури, *Карла Бруни: тайная жизнь*):

> **Поэтому только когда** она отправилась к нему за кулисы после одного из
>   концертов, ей удалось наконец подцепить его на крючок.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр! Интересный выход из ситуации: можно, но только в таком переделанном виде. :) Кстати, Вы не хотите ответить на мой вопрос про "не много"? Behemothus не понял аналогии с английским там, а Вы точно поймёте. А то получилась странная ситуация: мы с Sharon нашли полное понимание, и я до конца поддерживаю её видение ситуации, а behemothus говорит, что всё это ерунда, и объясняет всё по-своему, и хотелось бы, чтобы кто-то ещё разрешил это противоречие.

Comment: Я согласен с Sharon и написал бы раздельно: целое предложение присоединено в обоснование отрицания "многости". При слитном написании слова текст воспринимается с искажением, утвердительно: "взял кое-какое количество" - а этому побочному смыслу заключительная часть противоречит, что затрудняет чтение (в устном варианте помогает правильная интонация).

Comment: Спасибо! То есть Вы согласны, что у нас слитность/раздельность так же различает эти случаи, как и в английском присутствие/отсутствие неопределённого артикля соответственно? А насчёт логических ударений тоже согласны с Sharon (и со мной) и не согласны с behemothus-ом?

Comment: Да, есть некоторая аналогия, но влияют не только артикли, а и контекст, сравнительные степени и оговорки. В нашем случае слитное написание возможно в варианте "совсем немного" - тогда это стыкуется с окончанием предложения, поскольку достаточность отрицается (не "кое-что", а "весьма мало", _just_ a little bit и т. д.).

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой интересно, как можно быть несогласнім с Бегемотусом, коли Бегемотус по сути дела ничего вообще не сказал, кроме того, что он не понял, чего именно хочет Артем Луговой?!

Comment: Если речь идет об аналогии с английским, то да то я её просто не понимаю. В чем она?! Аналогия это когда в сходных ситуациях применяются сходные подходы. А вы даже не пояснили, в чем вы видите смысловую разницу при слитном и раздельном написании. Заговорили о каких-то ударениях (смысловых, надо полагать) т. е. акцентах, но их там нет в природе. Вот это и есть "ерунда" (слово ваше, я его не употреблял вроде - наученный модератором).

Comment: *А вы даже не пояснили, в чем вы видите смысловую разницу при слитном и раздельном написании.* При слитном написании смысл "сколько-то" или, как сказал Александр, "кое-какое количество", обычно достаточное. Исключение, правильно Александр сказал, "совсем немного" — здесь отрицается достаточность. А при раздельном написании смысл в том же отрицании достаточности: не много -> мало. Вы говорите, что не видите подчёркнутого отрицания в моём примере, а я только так и вижу — ну что тут поделаешь?..

Answer (score 0):

Нет, **к главному** отнести никак нельзя, ибо не может главное начинаться с подчинительного союза.

А вот отнести союз ко всему СПП (да и к ССП) вполне можно. Тот прием, о котором говорит Alex_ander, я именно так и расцениваю. Поэтому (что?) то-то и то-то. "Только" в отличие от "как только",  "если только" и проч. не является подчинительным союзом и это позволяет по-другому осмыслить грамматику фразы. Что и находит выражение в отсутствии запятой.

Это наводит на мысль, что и в исходном варианте отсутствие запятой не противоречит принятой грамматике. Но полностью противоречит пунктуационной практике. То есть мотив для написания без запятой в принципе имеется, но для этого надо пойти наперекор устоявшимся принципам. Эту тему можно было бы "потрясти", но вряд ли в том есть большой смысл. Просто переосмысление грамматики а данной фразе - забава не имеющая практического наполнения. Семантика фразы от того ну никак не изменится. А раз так, то и смысла выискивать неординарные решения нету никакого.

Comment: Всё понимаю, кроме первой фразы. К главному нельзя отнести, к придаточному тоже, так к чему же тогда можно?