# Нужна ли запятая после "поэтому"? (2)

Tags: запятые

*Поэтому когда речь заходит об обновлении, подразумевается вовсе не обновление, а обновление нашего понимания.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Поэтому когда речь заходит об обновлении***, подразумевается вовсе не обновление, а обновление нашего понимания.

В данном предложении запятую после наречия ***поэтому*** не ставим, так как переставить придаточное нельзя (у него здесь фиксированная позиция).

По смыслу текста **придаточное  должно стоять на первом месте** (идет повтор слов: об обновлении, но подразумевается не обновление...).

В других же случаях постановка запятой после наречия поэтому перед союзом **факультативная**, например:

**Поэтому, когда** Тома была маленькой, она была уверена, что Павел Алексеевич любит её больше, чем Таню.  [Людмила Улицкая. Казус Кукоцкого  2000]

**Поэтому, когда** осенью 1984 года в Большом театре был организован вечер памяти великого певца, снова был аншлаг. [И. К. Архипова. Музыка жизни (1996)]

**И поэтому когда** Христос даёт нам заповедь, Он нам не только указывает, что делать;  [митрополит Антоний (Блум). О жизни христианской (1990)]

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ 1**

1) Мне кажется некорректной такая перестановка: *Поэтому  подразумевается вовсе не обновление, а обновление нашего понимания, **когда речь заходит об обновлении.***

2)  Но есть еще зависимость **от контекста,** для окончательного решения нужен фрагмент текста.

3)  Обратите внимание на **вставочную интонацию** при обособлении придаточного: ударение на наречии, выделение придаточного паузами, произношение с понижением тона: *ПоЭтому,  **когда речь заходит об обновлении,** подразумевается вовсе не обновление, а обновление нашего понимания.*

4) Если Вас всё это устраивает, то вы можете принять свое авторское решение обособить придаточное, правилами это не запрещено. К сожалению, у Розенталя нет примеров СПП с эти наречием.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ 2**

Хотелось бы подробнее раскрыть тему **о факультативности обособления** придаточного после наречия ***поэтому***.

Скорее всего, здесь надо учитывать **ряд факторов**, а не только формальную перестановку придаточного. Многое зависит от **структуры** предложения, а также от **предыдущего** текста.

При обособлении мы дополнительно выделяем придаточное предложение **в отдельную структуру**, а всегда ли нужно такое дробление? Предложение может и так состоять из нескольких фраз, придаточное в них просто затеряется. Если это **уточнение**, то хорошо, а если нет? Тогда важные отношения между прждложениями могут уйти с первого плана.

**Надо ли выделять ударением наречие,** что неизбежно при обособлении? Если до этого подробно раскрывалась какая-то тема, то наречие **укажет на нее**, тогда это **положительный** момент, а если нет, то такая ударная позиция будет казаться **неоправданной**.

В целом это действительно **факультативное решение, рассчитанное на интуицию автора**, и тогда важной становится ориентация **на интонацию.** Прочитайте предложение дважды в разных вариантах. Правильным будет тот, который обеспечивает легкое прочтение и быстрое понимание текста.

Comment: Значит, у меня была другая ситуация: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/453105/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%91-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba?

Comment: Мой ответ неверен? Кратко его можно пересказать так. Запятая ставится факультативно, но в некоторых случаях, когда перестановка придаточного нарушает смысловые связи в СПП,  запятая после наречия "поэтому" не ставится.  Возможно, это не так, и у кого-то есть другое мнение? Мне было бы интересно услышать. В общем случае наречие может относится к придаточному, но, может быть, это особенное наречие? В словаре Кузнецова его называют союзным словом ( я с этим не согласна).

Comment: Да почему же неверен? Я просто спрашиваю как не понимающий в этом у понимающей. ;) В моём случае как? Можно поставить после "Димы", поэтому всё же нужна запятая? Или нет?

Comment: А разве нельзя рассуждать так: Поэтому подразумевается вовсе не обновление, а обновление нашего понимания. И в предложение вставляется пояснение (не знаю, как назвать правильно) "когда речь заходит об обновлении", которое обособляется. Что не так?

Comment: @ Рад  Пожалуйста, посмотрите дополнение к ответу.

Comment: @ Артём Луговой Артем, я " про Диму"  ничего не понимаю, по указанной  ссылке даже нет моего ответа. Я бы в вашем примере обособила придаточное: его можно переставить; кроме того сочетание "поэтому как только"  неудобно для чтения в одну фразу.

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon! Значит, подтверждается то, что мне и раньше сказали. :)

Comment: Кстати, когда вы собачку отделяете от имени, мне уведомления не приходит. А вот когда имя и фамилию разделяют, вроде обычно доходит. (Сам пишу вместе, п. ч. всё равно с собакой уже не обычным обращением получается. ;))